# Two different coding standards

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I would like to know if there is a way to work on one C# code standard but before committing the code change the format of the files to a different one in Visual Studio 2017.

I like to work with braces in the same line but would like to, once I'm done, update all the files to use braces on a new line before committing the code to source control.  Also, I would like the ability to open the files I need to work with and have them formatted the way I like them

Is there a way to accomplish this without importing different settings before committing the code?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I am using prettier. Together with pre-commit tools like husky, you can [reformat the code](https://prettier.io/docs/en/precommit.html) during the commit.

I don't know if you can define a custom format during coding beside of prettier or give prettier a diffrent config for coding and committing, but perhaps you give it a try.

Comment: That looks like the type of solution I'm looking for.  Unfortunately, it does not work with c#, which now that I noticed, I did not mentioned on the post.  Thanks for the link, will definitely try it for my front end work.